# How to jump to a specific tab located in another page in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a button and I have another page in the same folder with some bootstrap Nav tabs. Now I want that when a user click on the button and that user will redirected to the bootstrap tab content.

Comment: do you mean anchor?

Comment: Yes, when a user clicks on the anchor that will be redirected to the specific tab.

Comment: by tab do you mean browser tab?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are sending the users there,

```
window.location.replace('yournextpage#anchor');
```

or

```
<a href="yournextpage#anchor">Continue</a>
```

where #anchor is the id of the element you want user to be directed to.